# Error #1090: XML parser failure: element is malformed

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

someone pls tell me what this erorr is about!?

the erorr:

```
TypeError: Error #1090: XML parser failure: element is malformed.

at Function/Classes:Image_SS/$construct/Classes:processXML()[D:\*\Classes\Image_SS.as:73]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

the code (Image_SS.as):

```
function processXML(e:Event):void
        {
            var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data); <--- this is line 73 >>>>>>>>
            if (where == "3D_solid_surface_1")
            {
                images = myXML.IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_1;
            }
            else if (where == "3D_solid_surface_2")
            {
                images = myXML.IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_2;
            }
            else if (where == "3D_solid_surface_3")
            {
                images = myXML.IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_3;
            }
            else if (where == "3D_solid_surface_4")
            {
                images = myXML.IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_4;
            }
            else if (where == "3D_solid_surface_closer_view")
            {
                images = myXML.IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C;
            }

            image_figure = images.length();

            myXMLLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
            myXMLLoader = null;

            the rest of the code ...
        }
```

the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GALLERY>
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_1 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/1-1.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/1-1.jpg"
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_1 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/1-2.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/1-2.jpg"
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_2 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/2-1.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/2-1.jpg"
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_2 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/2-2.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/2-2.jpg"
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_3 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/3-1.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/3-1.jpg"
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_4 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/4-1.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/4-1.jpg"
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_4 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/4-2.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/4-2.jpg"
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/C_1.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/C_1.jpg"
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/C_2.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/C_2.jpg"
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/C_3.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/C_3.jpg"
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/C_4.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/C_4.jpg"
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/C_5.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/C_5.jpg"
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/C_6.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/C_6.jpg"
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/C_7.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/C_7.jpg"
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/C_8.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/C_8.jpg"
</GALLERY>
```

i have used the same code somewhere else with a little change. But this time it's not working. I don't know why!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget add closing tag to "IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_1" elements.

try this new  XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GALLERY>
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_1 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/1-1.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/1-1.jpg" />
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_1 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/1-2.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/1-2.jpg" />
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_2 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/2-1.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/2-1.jpg" />
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_2 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/2-2.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/2-2.jpg" />
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_3 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/3-1.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/3-1.jpg" />
     <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_4 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/4-1.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/4-1.jpg" /> 
</GALLERY>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your close tags?

```
<GALLERY>
        <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_1 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/1-1.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/1-1.jpg"></IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_1>
        <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_1 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/1-2.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/1-2.jpg"></IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_1>
        <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_2 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/2-1.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/2-1.jpg"></IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_2>
        <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_2 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/2-2.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/2-2.jpg"></IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_2>
        <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_3 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/3-1.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/3-1.jpg"></IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_3>
        <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_4 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/4-1.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/4-1.jpg"></IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_4>
        <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_4 FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/4-2.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/4-2.jpg"></IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_4>
        <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/C_1.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/C_1.jpg"></IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C>
        <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/C_2.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/C_2.jpg"></IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C>
        <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/C_3.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/C_3.jpg"></IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C>
        <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/C_4.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/C_4.jpg"></IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C>
        <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/C_5.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/C_5.jpg"></IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C>
        <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/C_6.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/C_6.jpg"></IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C>
        <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/C_7.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/C_7.jpg"></IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C>
        <IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C FULL="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/C_8.jpg" THUMB="Gallery/3D_solid_surface/small/C_8.jpg"></IMAGE_3D_solid_surface_C>
</GALLERY>
```